# What is wrong with the simple code in Keras below?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am struggling for the last hour to understand what i am doing wrong. I am a novice in NN, but this is not my first code.

```
def simple_model(lr=0.1):
    X = Input(shape=(6144,))
    out = Dense(1)(X)
    model = Model(inputs=X, outputs=out)
    opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=lr)
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='mean_squared_error')
    model.summary()
    return model

mod = simple_model()
a = np.zeros(6144)
v = mod.predict(a)
```

running this i get the following error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 6144) for input Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(None, 6144), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (32, 1).
......
ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 6144 but received input with shape [32, 1]
```

Where does this [32, 1] come from ?!
I am sure there is some silly mistake in my code, but can't see it :(
p.s. It does compile the mode and prints the summary before throwing an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mod = simple_model()
a = np.zeros(6144)
#Add this line
a = np.expand_dims(a,axis=0)
v = mod.predict(a)
```

The reason why your error appears is that Keras + TensorFlow only allow batch predictions. When we use `expand_dims` function, we actually create a batch of dimension 1.

Comment: Yes, that was silly indeed .. Thank you! :) Previous times i used Keras, i passed in already expanded data, so didn't notice

Comment: No issue. If it solved your problem, would you mind also accepting the answer as the solving one? Thank you.

Comment: @Yes, I also ran into this issue when I was a bit more inexperienced, some tutorials with data already expanded and when I coded on my own I forgot to expand_dims :D

Comment: Yep, will accept as soon as it allows me to. Says "wait 5 minutes".
Still interesting where does [32, 1] come from, but that's just curiosity :)